# Why has Britain not taken action if they settled on an agreement?

Tags: united-kingdom, china, hong-kong

I've been hearing about the conflicts in Hong Kong and that China had opened an office and Hongkongers are losing their rights they supposed to have in their democracy. From the Sino-British Joint Declaration deal China and Britain made, it would grant Hongkongers the Freedom of the democratic order (freedom of speech, right to live, freedom of assembly...). Well, what I don't understand is if China and Britain made a deal and one doesn't hold onto it and misleads, wouldn`t the other have to fight. So if China misleads the deal according to the Joint Declaration why is Britain not doing more to secure the deal or change perspective leading Hongkong. This is also a stupid question but could also such a deal be taken down?

Note: This question is not meant to advocate any specific political position. I am just thinking about it logically!

Comment: What exactly is that "more" you would expect "Britain" (I think you mean the United Kingdom) to be doing?

Comment: I mean that Britain is supposed to fight for the freedom of democratic order or fight for what was made in the deal. I would also like it if the last question could be answered

Comment: What concrete measures are you talking about when you write "fight for the freedom"? The UK *did* take actions to condemn the Chinese actions regarding Hong Kong, but it is not clear if you consider those inadequate or if you just aren't aware of them.

Comment: I am also not sure what exactly you mean with the last paragraph "This question is not meant to be a political-based question". This is Politics Stack Exchange, so we expect all questions on this website to be about politics.

Comment: I meant this question to be neutral

Comment: @Gregory I've edited that part of your question. But I would still like to ask you to also address the other clarification requests I made: What *precisely* would you expect the UK to do? And are you already aware of what they already did, like officially condemning the national security law and granting HK citizens path to UK citzenship?

Comment: @Philipp "Britain" (not "Great Britain") is a pretty standard English language shorthand for the UK. The demonym for UKians, after all, is "British".

Answer (score 3):

**Britain *has* taken action, but its options are limited by China's determination to assert greater control over Hong Kong.**

There is a strong political consensus in Britain across the political spectrum that China should respect its earlier commitment to "one country, two systems". In response, Boris Johnson has made it easier for Hong Kong citizens to emigrate to the UK. [As reported by *The Diplomat*](https://thediplomat.com/2020/06/hong-kong-and-britains-china-reset/), "Britain, Australia, Canada, and the United States released a joint statement expressing deep concerns over the proposed new security legislation," in early June.

To quote further from the same article:

> China’s response has included strong rhetoric and hints of revenge. The Foreign Ministry in Beijing insists that the U.K. has no sovereignty or jurisdiction over Hong Kong, nor any right to interfere in China’s internal affairs. Britain, in its view, is clinging to a colonialist mindset.

It also mentions that "China’s huge economic power puts Britain at a disadvantage". The COVID crisis and Brexit constrain Britain's leverage even further. **It's hard to imagine Britain escalating conflict with China any time soon, especially over an issue which for Britain is of mostly symbolic significance.**